# How to make an iFrame window scrolls with overflow:hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, joomla1.5

I want to make the iframe window of modal box in Joomla 1.5 to scroll, but without scrollbars to appear. If I set `overflow:hidden` through css it works in Chrome, but not in Firefox! Does anybody have any idea how can I do this? Any trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Overflow: hidden` is supposed to give the appearance that a container cannot scroll (i.e. hiding the scroll bars. The fact that is works for you in Chrome is just a *quirk* of Chrome, not standard. My suggestion would be to leave the scrollbars on the iframe but hide it with either a floating div or with the parent container. So for example, put the iframe inside a div. Force the div width to 18px (guestimated width of scrollbar) less than the width of the iframe with overflow: hidden. The frame will continue to scroll with the mouse wheel but you will not be able to see the scrollbar.

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/nLG85/).

Html:

```
<div><iframe src="http://afakesite.com/"></iframe></div>​
```

CSS:

```
iframe {
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
}
div {
    width: 182px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

Comment: To be honest, overflow:hidden and scrolling, works everywhere else except Firefox!!! I have already find this example but I though that maybe there is something more... hm... standard!!! Anyway thank you very much for your answer!!! :)

Comment: @GreenMadness. I'll +1 your question to even it out! You could do with some rep :) (P.S. You're question actually got two downvotes. Anonymous downvotes should be banned!)